# Summation Proof - Permutation of indices

Tags: proof-verification, summation

How do i mathematically prove that

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^N b_{n+1} = \sum\limits_{n=2}^{N+1} b_n$

This was taken from the proof of telescoping Series

See: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Telescoping_Series

It says here it's due to permutation of indices. I don't know what this is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the first and last term in each series, noting what must be between..
$$\sum_{n=1}^N b_{n+1} = b_{((1)+1)} + \dots + b_{((N)+1)} = b_2 + \dots + b_{N+1} = \sum_{n=2}^{N+1} b_{n}$$

Or, alternatively, let $a_n$ = $b_{n+1}$, so for $n>1$, $b_n = a_{n-1}$ and
$$\sum_{n=2}^{N+1} b_{n} = \sum_{n=2}^{N+1} a_{n-1} = \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{N} b_{n+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Write out:

$$ b_2 + b_3 + ... + b_{N+1} = ... $$